# python- splitting an array into sub arrays dependant on value (opencv- image cropping)

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, image-segmentation, dot-matrix

I am trying to crop an image of dot matrix print into individual characters. I have dilated the characters, threhold and inverted them.

[image: SEGMENTAION]

I have created an array that has the pixel values of the blank spaces in the image. (the red lines) in order to crop individual characters

[image: array of spaces]

I am trying to write a function that will return the pixels of the character eg

L - [0 62]

o - [74 137]

r - [149 199]
etc.

I have tried a couple of methods of for loops but canot reach a solution to produce the required arrays.  Any tips appreciated!

```
##dot matrix print
##import the required libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np

## import the image
image = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Downloads/dot-matrix-unknown-sample.png')

##create the kernal for the dilation
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)

##crop the image to one line
cropped =image[0:101, 0:]

##crop the first letter 'l'
##l = cropped[0:101, 0:62]

## convert the image to gray and use the otsu threshold and invert
img=cv2.cvtColor(cropped,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(th3)

##dilate the dots in the matrixto take up the gaps between the dots.
dilation = cv2.dilate(inverted,kernel,iterations = 1)

##display the image
cv2.imshow('img',dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

##provides the location of spaces in the image in 2d arrray
vpp = np.sum(dilation, axis =0)
space= np.where(vpp == 0)
space= np.array(space)

##convert to a 1d array (as image)
space=space.ravel()
print(space)
```

p.s if there is a better way to do this please sugggest.

Comment: Possible approach: 1) Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsus' threshold to get a binary image. 2) Create rectangular shaped kernel and dilate 3) Find contours and find x,y,w,h ROI coordinates with boundingRect. Then use Numpy slicing to crop ROI or drawContours to draw bounding rectangle. You're very close, just find contours on your dilation image, then find bounding rectangle coordinates

Answer (score 2):

I assume the output you want bounding box for each letter.

Steps:

1.Dilate the image to bring contours (dots) closer

2- Find the
contours

3- Sort Contours According to the sizes of their bounding
boxes

4- Remove Unwanted contours if any (I did this by taking only
largest 2 contours, where 2 is number of letters in my test case.

5-Sort contours according to their X positions (left to right, I dont
know if this is necessary for you)

6- Find bounding boxes for each
coordinate, optionally draw it

**Code:**

```
# Dilate
dilated = cv2.dilate(gray, (5, 5), iterations=8)

# Find Contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Sort the contours descending according to their area
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=False)

NUMBER_OF_LETTERS = 2
# Delete the smalles contours to match len(contours) to number of letters.
del contours[len(contours) - NUMBER_OF_LETTERS]

# Sort the Contours According to their position (left to right)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0], reverse=True)

bboxes = []

# Find and draw bounding boxes, and append to bboxes list for future use.
for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    bboxes.append((x, y, w, h))
    cv2.rectangle(dot_matrix, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

**Output: (Original, Dilated, BoundingBoxes)**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, obviously you have got it to work.

to show the image with the bounding boxs did you use cv2.imshow('img',cv2.rectangle(dot_matrix, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2) ??

Comment: @Tam sorry for the late reply, cv2.rectangle function draws a rectangle on given image. So on the last line I drawn the rectangle on dot_matrix img. So I used cv2.imshow("img", dot_matrix)